# DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to Javascript. I've heard that DOM is the most important aspect of Javascript, it's used all the time, DOM allows us to add all the interactivity to the webpages, blah blah blah...

...But I see DOM as nothing but a mere hierarchical representation of HTML elements. I don't get it why it's given so much importance. What am I missing?

Also, I heard in a tutorial that DOM of a webpage is created when it loads on the browser. My question is, what creates it? Is it the rendering machine?

Comment: DOM is the most important aspect of writing Javascript in a client side web aspect.

Comment: READ: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: "*But I see DOM as nothing but a mere hierarchical representation of HTML elements.*" Yes, that's why it's important. What good would client-side scripting be if there was no way to inspect or manipulate the contents of a web page? To understand its importance, try to imagine how you would possibly perform any useful scripting *without* the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

> But I see DOM as nothing but a mere hierarchical representation of HTML elements. I don't get it why it's given so much importance. What am I missing?

Because "a mere hierarchical representation of HTML elements" is a webpage and lots of people want to manipulate the webpage that the user is viewing. It's probably the most common thing people want to use JS for.

> what creates it?

The browser.